# How can I change language of my application?

Tags: android

In my application I have a option of language selection.

There are three languages: English, German & Spanish. When I select an option, the entire application language should be changed.

How can I make this possible?

Comment: please look at the preview window when you prepare a question, and don't use HTML tags directly, use the editor controls. Your question text was not showing at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to use another language than the default language in the phone? I have that in one application, and this is what I had to do.

Add this to your activity declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    :
    :
</activity>
```

And then invoke a method like this from `onCreate` in your activity:

```
public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setting language");
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); //e.g "sv"
    Locale systemLocale = SystemLocale.getInstance().getCurrentLocale(context);
    if (systemLocale != null && systemLocale.equals(locale)) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Already correct language set");
       return;
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Log.d(TAG, "Language set");
}
```

Comment: So, after doing above two things i just need to create the resoures file (R.String.Values.xml for specific language support) and bases on the app Settings i can set the language of the app run time. Right ?

Comment: Where did you get the SystemLocale and TAG?

Answer (score 0):

You just add the value folder according to the language.
For example, I have added 3 languages: English, Arabic and Hindi.
In `res` folder create `values-ar` for arabic and `values-hi` for hindi to hold all strings used in application.
Now I have a listview of languages. So when the user clicks on one of the language, the language of application will be changed and the phone language will remain same. 
Here is the code ..

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            String language = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if (language.equals("English")) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("en");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources()
                        .updateConfiguration(
                                config,
                                getBaseContext().getResources()
                                        .getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(ChangeLanguage.this, "Locale in English",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (language.equals("Arabic")) {

                Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources()
                        .updateConfiguration(
                                config,
                                getBaseContext().getResources()
                                        .getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(ChangeLanguage.this, "Locale in Arabic",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (language.equals("Hindi")) {

                Locale locale = new Locale("hi");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources()
                        .updateConfiguration(
                                config,
                                getBaseContext().getResources()
                                        .getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(ChangeLanguage.this, "Locale in Hindi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ChangeLanguage.this,
                        "Locale in not changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), language,
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
             */

            GetterSetter.getInstance().setLanguage(changelanguage);
            startActivity(new Intent(ChangeLanguage.this,
                    MainSettings.class));
            main.tabhost.setCurrentTab(3);
        }
    });
```