# How to convert language from English to Arabic?

Tags: android, localization

I have created an App in english language and its working fine. Now i want to convert this English language to Arebic. I am following this link. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236052/how-can-i-change-language-of-my-application) .But not getting properly. Can Anybody tell me any tutorial OR any references for this?

Comment: please suggest me if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add a translation, please study this manual: [Localization Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource folder:
res/values-ar

Copy your strings.xml file from res/values into this folder and translate the english strings in this file to arabic.