# Android locale language support

Tags: android, locale

How do you add new locales to android.
I'm looking for a way to get Japanese installed such that the phone will report JAPAN or JAPANESE as locale.
I have found apps like simeji that adds Japanese keyoard support.
But cant figure out how to install new language packages for specific languages.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236052/how-can-i-change-language-of-my-application

Answer (score 5):

You can overwrite the Language Settings of the Android device with this code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
Locale locale = new Locale("ja");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        config.locale = locale;
        ((Activity) c).getBaseContext().getResources()
            .updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

If you said its hidden in the OS and your users just cant select it, this might work.

But if the device has this language not installed, it will be impossible to achieve your goal. You cant just install a new language onto the device.

Edit: If you add this code to the Start of your App, the Phone will report being japanese despite the SystemLanguage. So it will use your "values-ja" for example.

Having the SystemLanguage installed only matters for SystemValues like preset submit buttons for example.

So you can just let the phone behave like its japanese without knowing any japanese. It will just take your japanese resources.

There might only be one problem, you would have to create your own keyboard if the System has no Japanese Keyboard installed.

See http://tutorials-android.blogspot.de/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

I'm not 100% if this really works with japanese because i dont know if those phones who cant select japanese know how to draw japanese letters, but they should be able to.

Comment: "If you said its hidden in the OS and your users just cant select it, this might work."

Well i don't actually know what locale the user device is installed 
with.

"But if the device has this language not installed, it will be impossible to achieve your goal. You cant just install a new language onto the device."

That is was what i fearing. But then, would it be possible to rebuild the device with an other android installation or is that in the control of the phone operator?

Comment: Yes you'd have to root the phone and basically install a clean android version on it. however, depending on the thing you want to do it might not even be necessary to have the system in that language. I will edit my post shortly

Comment: I'm using the locale to auto-switch into the native language in my application

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [Android Localisation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: I already did.
But i need to know how to add a language pack to the phone device.
Some of my customers can not select Japanese from the device settings.
The language might be hidden in the OS someware, but it is not applicable.
If the customer cant install the locale, the device wont be able to switch to Japanese.
Sorry for the confusion. But Android language support is a bit weird.