# Letting user choose language at application level

Tags: android, internationalization

I have localized my android app and localized text is displayed when user switches his local on the device.

But what if user actually wants my app to show text in English and still don't change his locale. Is there any thing I can do in my app like asking if he wants to set locale at my app level. If he chooses so, how will I make my app presume that the locale in English and not German (I mean is there any API like setDefaultLocale())?

Comment: have u refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236117/1915697

Comment: have u got the answer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer it :-  [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236117/1915697) 
or

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    :
    :
</activity>
```

And then invoke a method like this from onCreate in your activity:

```
public static void setLanguage(Context context, String languageToLoad) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setting language");
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); //e.g "sv"
    Locale systemLocale = SystemLocale.getInstance().getCurrentLocale(context);
    if (systemLocale != null && systemLocale.equals(locale)) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Already correct language set");
       return;
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Log.d(TAG, "Language set");
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CRUSADER Usually correct, though in this there is some redundancy due to the link being on SE. Anyway, this should then be a "related:" comment

Comment: @YogeshTatwal The correct behaviour, since this questions is basically the same as the one you link to, is closing (or flagging) this as a duplicate instead of duplicating the answer